# How can my makefile include subdirectories?

Tags: makefile, subdirectory

(updated for clarity) (solution added at bottom)

I found a makefile online which builds all the cpp files in that directory and compiles them.

But I can't work out how I can include files inside a subdirectory.

Here's a breakdown of what happens:

- I create the files test.cpp & test.hpp and place them inside the sub-directory '/gui' which is contained within my working directory, they contain the function testFunction().
- Without including test.hpp, I type "make" into terminal and I receive the error:

:

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:6:2: error: 'testFunction' was not declared in this scope
  testFunction();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
```

- If I include (#include "gui/test.hpp"), I then receive a different error:

:

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++  main.o -Wall  -o testfile
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `testFunction()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:34: testfile] Error 1
```

- But if I then add "-I/gui" or (at a guess) "-I./gui" to CFLAGS, I get the exact same error message.

Here's the makefile for reference:

```
TARGET = testfile
LIBS = 
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.hpp)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Updated makefile since accepted answer:

(Changes were to include directories, CC replaced with CXX, and %.c replaced with %.cpp)

```
TARGET = testfile
DIRS =
LDLIBS =

CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS= -g -Wall

# this ensures that if there is a file called default, all or clean, it will still be compiled
.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

# substitute '.cpp' with '.o' in any *.cpp 
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp $(addsuffix /*.cpp, $(DIRS))))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

# build the executable
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
# if make is interupted, dont delete any object file
.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

# build the objects
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LDLIBS) -o $@ 

clean:
    -rm -f *.o $(addsuffix /*.o, $(DIRS))
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: "No luck" is not a problem we can help with. Please edit your question and add in (a) the make command you invoked, (b) the compile line that make printed, and (c) the error messages that you got; also useful will be (d) the actual `#include` line in your source code related to the error.  Please cut and paste them as they appear (no screenshots or shorthand references) properly formatted.  Then we can help.  BTW, it's unlikely that `-I/gui` is right, unless you have a directory `/gui` on your system (you can run `ls /gui` and see the files you want).

Comment: Are you talking about source files or headers?

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for your responses, I have updated the question, hopefully it is a bit more clear now? let me know if not :)

Comment: @Beta because the error changes when I include the header file, I assume it is the source it cannot find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what's happening here you have to look up the definitions of *declaration* versus *definition* in C++ (and other languages).  You should definitely do that.

A declaration (typically put into a header file) is like the address of your house.  If someone wants to send you a letter, they need your address.  If your main function wants to call another function like `testFunction()`, it needs the declaration of the function.

The first error happens because you don't have the header file included, so the compiler doesn't have the declaration of the function you want to call, which means it won't compile your calling function.

But for the letter to actually arrive, you need your actual house.  The address is the declaration and your house is the definition... in this case the actual function implementation.  That lives in `test.cpp` file.  When you link your code together, the linker (in this scenario I guess the linker is like the postal service :p :) ) will try to link up the call to the definition.

However, you can see that you are not compiling the `test.cpp` file nor are you linking the object file:

```
g++  main.o -Wall  -o testfile
```

here we see `main.o`, but not `gui/test.o`.

Why not?  This line:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
```

Matches all `*.cpp` files and converts them into `.o` files.  But `*.cpp` matches only files in the current directory, like `main.cpp`.  If you want to put files in a different directory you have to tell make where they are; for example:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp gui/*.cpp))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that seems to have fixed the problem. I was pretty sure it wasn't seeing it at all, but I think it's my makefile knowledge which has hindered me here... it's not a very intuitive language. Is there any way i could go about creating a variable in my make file which allows me to cleanly add multiple directories? for example DIRS = gui otherdir otherdir2? and have the line something like OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp $(DIRS)/*.cpp))

Comment: It's not a procedural languages.  It's a declarative language.  It's very appropriate for its task but if you've never worked with declarative languages before it can be confusing.  Also, as with most things programming, grabbing some random file off of the web somewhere is not really the best way to learn :).  Better would be to write your own makefile, using something like https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html

Comment: sorry i edited the last message so you may not have seen this: Is there any way i could go about creating a variable in my make file which allows me to cleanly add multiple directories? for example DIRS = gui otherdir otherdir2? and have the line something like OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard .cpp $(DIRS)/.cpp))

Comment: Sure: `OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(DIRS))))`

Comment: Absolute legend! This is significantly going to clean up my projects! Thanks! :)

Comment: I have another issue regarding this, I was hoping you might be able to help? Originally this makefile was used to compile C projects. But I have since moved into the realms of C++. I changed "CC = gcc" to "CC = gpp", "%.c" to "%.cpp" & "%.h" to "%.hpp", and it compiles fine, however all of my CFLAGS are now not included when I make (my output looks like "g++    -c -o file.o file.cpp" for each output file, whereas before there was "-g -Wall" after g++. Any idea why g++ is removing my flags in this makefile? thanks!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Don't be fooled by the fact that they both start with "C" and have some similarities.  They are different languages, and you can build objects from both and link them togeter.  In make, they have different rules for how they are built, and those rules use different make variables to control them.  The variable holding the C++ compiler is `CXX`, not `CC` and the variable holding flags for the C++ compiler is `CXXFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`.

Comment: You solved my problem again :) Thank you so much! I always assumed that CC & FLAGS where just user defined variable names, I never would have guessed that they are inbuilt terms in make! Now I can finally debug again!

Comment: There is a set of predefined implicit rules make has bult-in.  These predefined rules use a set of predefined variables.  You can find them in the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html  If you want to use the built-in rules you control them by modifying the built-in variables.  If you want to write your own rules you can use whatever variables you want but it's wise to use the same ones just to be clear.

Comment: Ahh thank you! some good info there. Looks like my LIBS variable should actually be named LDLIBS then

Comment: I apologise for bugging you again, but I have noticed that my makefile doesn't notice when I make updates to header files. I have tried a number of changes but I have not had any luck. Is there something you could suggest? Thanks in advance

Comment: make is a general purpose tool.  It has no understanding of what kind of text exists inside any files it deals with.  If you want your targets to recompile, you have to explicitly list all their prerequisites in your makefile; make won't go look inside your source files to try to find prerequisites (such as header files) on its own.  If you've listed the headers as prerequisites in your makefile it should work: if it doesn't please ask a new question with full details.  Asking a completely different question in the comments of an earlier question isn't how StackOverflow is meant to be used.

Comment: If what you're asking is for ways for make to automatically figure out what header files your object files depend on this can be done but requires some understanding of how compilers work and special options they provide.  You can read this for example: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/  If you have a simple setup with just a limited number of source files and header files and you aren't adding more very often, it's probably easier to just list them directly yourself in your makefile.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, the issue I had was for make to recognise changes in the header files of my cpp files, rather than finding a list of all dependant headers. But i actually solved the issue, the line: "%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)" should have had %.cpp. It since seems to recognise any changes in my headers now. thanks for the help :)

Comment: That says, "if any header file `*.h` changes, recompile all the object files`.  That is sufficient for simple environments, or environments where (almost) all the source files include (almost) all the header files anyway.  If you get to the point where you want to recompile only the specific object files that use the header file that changes and not recompile object files that don't use the header file, you need to get more sophisticated.

Comment: Noted, I should be okay for the time being as my projects are only small-medium sized... so far! Thanks for all your help :)